# What would be the "date created" of a file that takes 10 minute to create?

Tags: windows, filesystems, date-time

Let's suppose Windows creates a file that takes 10 minutes to create. For example, a user records a video for 10 minutes starting at 12:00 am. What would be the "date created" time for that file? 12:00 am or 12:10 am?

Same question for "date modified" but using another example: user saves a file that takes 10 minutes to save.

Comment: Most applications generate a 0 byte file then fill that file with data.  What time(s) would be indicated on this attribute would depend on how the file is created.

Comment: Good point by Ramhound. And, if the program writes to a temp file first (not necessarily in `%TEMP%`) and then creates the final file at the end, the date created would 12:10 AM. It's up to the program how it saves the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is always created *instantly*, the moment a program opens it. It's only filling it with data that takes time. (That is, the process is "open new file - write data - write… - write… - close file". There *isn't* a "create file with data" function.)

So the timestamps would likely be:

- Created: 12:00 AM *(i.e. when the 'open()' function was used)*
- Last modified: 12:10 AM *(i.e. when the last 'write()' was issued)*

In many cases, this applies even when going through a temporary file – most programs create the file only once, and then just move it to the final location when done (which preserves creation time.)

(And if the program *copies* the temporary file to the destination, then creation time would be "the moment the copying started" – again, the moment the new file was open()'ed.)

If you're particularly curious, you could use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see exactly what happens.